# jq - selecting an item if the nth element of a nested dict matches

Tags: json, jq

I have line delimited JSON data like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 671731542,
    "type": "BeReq",
    "records": [
      { "tag": "foo", "value": "bar" },
      { "tag": "foo", "value": "bar" },
      { "tag": "RespStatus", "value": "200" },
      { "tag": "RespReason", "value": "OK" },
      { "tag": "foo", "value": "bar" },
      { "tag": "RespStatus", "value": "304" },
      { "tag": "RespReason", "value": "Not Modified" }
    ]
  }
]
[
  {
    "id": 671731543,
    "type": "BeReq",
    "records": [
      { "tag": "foo", "value": "bar" },
      { "tag": "foo", "value": "bar" },
      { "tag": "RespStatus", "value": "200" },
      { "tag": "RespReason", "value": "OK" }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to be able to filter based on the nth `RespStatus` inside the `records` array. I can filter items by *any* `RespStatus` like:

```
jq '.[] | select(.records[] | .tag=="RespStatus" and .value=="304")' < requests.log
```

but sometimes I need to filter if only the nth `RespStatus` is `304`.

Comment: So for your sample input, the result would be empty?

Comment: I just updated the question, but in the sample I'd want to verify that the second `RespStatus` in the array is 304. Sometimes it might be the first, sometimes the third. In the original question though, yes it wouldn't have returned anything if I wanted the first `RespStatus` that is `304`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`nth`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#first-last-nth-2) filter to extract the element matching your criterion:

```
.[] | select(nth(1;.records[]|select(.tag=="RespStatus")).value=="304")
```

(zero-based)

Alternatively, map the array and then [access by index](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#array-index):

```
.[] | select(.records|map(select(.tag=="RespStatus"))[1].value=="304")
```

(again zero-based; it needs to allocate a new array)

Comment: Sorry, I should've mentioned there could be any number of other tagged elements in the `records` array, so `RespStatus` may not be the literal first item. I'd also want to be able to filter by the nth `RespStatus`, so it has to filter only the `RespStatus` tagged items first, then filter by the `value` of the nth result.

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much! I had looked at `nth`, but had the logic backwards.